# How do I translate strings in Twig templates?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am working on a (my first) Drupal 8 project witch is a multilingual site. Drupal 8 really delivers in terms of native support for content translation. 
However, I have a few strings set directly in some if the theme .Twig template files printed out like ex.

```
{{ 'Read more'|trans }}
```

I am really stuck on where to handle the translation for strings like these within the Drupal 8 installation.

What steps do I need to take to be able to translate these strings into the language currently selected for on the site? Do I need any additional modules other than the ones included in Drupal 8 core?

Steps I have taken:

- Activated the Content Translation & Interface Translation modules
- Added Twig strings like {{ 'Read more'|trans }}
- Flushed cache and refreshed pages containing the strings
- Checked admin/config/regional/translate for the strings with no result

Comment: Have you tried use `|t` instead of `|trans`?

Comment: @Vagner I have added the strings as shown in my question, where the string is suffixed with |trans

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to visit the page in a language that is not English to have them picked up. That should be enough.

Comment: Figures that it should be so easy. I have reloaded the page in several languages but not in the one where i had this problem. Just as you said the strings are translatable once you visit the page using that language setting. Thanks!

Comment: You also have to be logged out

Answer (score 38):

Use the `t` filter:

```
{{ 'translate me'|t }}
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates

Answer (score 26):

You can use the `{% trans %}` Twig tag, available in Drupal 8:

```
{% trans %}
  Submitted by {{ author.username }} on {{ node.created }}
{% endtrans %}
```

See the following link for more details: http://getlevelten.com/blog/mark-carver/drupal-8-twig-templates-and-translations

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have read through that article as well but unfortunately it does not cover where I handle the translation for the strings added to the template files using {% trans %} or |trans, or |t. :S

Comment: Thanks for the post. This work for me. After adding this code: {% trans %} Categories {% endtrans %} I cleared the cache and go to admin/config/regional/translate page. Where I searched my keyword "Categories" and get a textfield for translating the word in French (as an example) language. After this, I get the translated word in required place.

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: This does not work for me. I've added the strings to my Twig files as {{ 'my string' | t }}. I then cleared cache and visited pages in the target language, multiple times. I still can't find the strings on the /admin/config/regional/translate page.

Answer (score 14):

This question have already been answered correctly, but if you need to translate a string with variables, here's how you do it.

```
{{ 'Subscribe to @title'|t({'@title': title}) }}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example I used where the language is explict provided, as well as an context. Like this I was able to translate the sting 'von' twice, as in english it meant 'of' or 'from'.

`{{ 'von'|t([],{'langcode': currentLanguageCode,'context':'Seitenzahl PDF' }) }}`

Answer (score 2):

You can translate string in twig using the following functions.

You need to visit the page so the string is added in the translation database.

**With filter**

```
{{ 'Hello Earth.'|trans }}
{{ 'Hello Earth.'|t }}
```

**with trans**

```
{% trans %}
  Submitted by {{ author.username }} on {{ node.created }}
{% endtrans %}
```

**with variables**

```
<p class="submitted">{{ "Submitted by !author on @date"|t({ '!author': author, '@date': date }) }}</p>
```

**plural**

```
{% set count = comments|length %}
{% trans %}
  {{ count }} comment was deleted successfully.
{% plural count %}
  {{ count }} comments were deleted successfully.
{% endtrans %}
```

This is also documented here https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates#trans

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Drupal considers custom translated strings as "User interface translation". To translate those, install "User interface translation" extend and then you find "User interface translation" in the configuration. There is a long list of strings, but your strings should located in the last section.

Answer (score 1):

this one helped me

```
{{ 'Read more'|trans }}
```

after this visit the page in a language that is not Original language to have them picked up by Drupal.

```
/admin/config/regional/translate
```

that s all.

Answer (score 1):

What was suggested [in this answer above](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/218939/107210) is what fixed the bug to me. It was impossible to me to find the strings. I went to the last page at

```
/admin/config/regional/translate
```

and there it was, but the search bar couldn't find it.