# Can't find my translations

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm creating a custom multilingual template. I used {% trans %} function in the twig. After adding new language I could not found the text i placed between trans tag. Do I need to configure sth more to get these strings into drupal's translations panel ?

```
   {% trans %}   Do you have any ideas or questions? Feel free to contact us, using the form below.  {% endtrans %}
```

Comment: You have to load the page once in the target language, see [How do I translate strings in Twig templates?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192498/how-do-i-translate-strings-in-twig-templates)

Comment: The translation is at contact page. I've visited this page with the language prefix. The language has been detected (I've checked via php) and i cannot find them at user interface translations