# How do I translate the weekday in a date?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, datetime

I created a view from a JSON file; the dates in that file follow the *2020-07-28 20:00* format. I do a rewrite of the date to `<span>{{ value_1|date("l d/m/Y") }}</span>` and I get *Tuesday 28/07/2020*, but I want to get the weekday in Dutch.

Is there code for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the below example as a temporal solution, I'm not sure if this is the proper way. The approach is to split the problem.

```
{{ value_1|date("l")|t }} {{ value_1|date("d/m/Y") }}
```

Regarding the next link, the proper use of translation on twig is using "t" filter.
[How do I translate strings in Twig templates?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192498/how-do-i-translate-strings-in-twig-templates)

Comment: thnx @diego-restrepo